# Ubuntu 21: sudo apt install failed, causing by gcc-11-base unmet dependencies on libgfortran5 :(

Tags: dependencies, gcc, raspberrypi, 21.04, opencv

My `sudo apt install` encountered problem when trying to install OpenCV. It fails on package `libgfortran5`, which OpenCV and libopencv-dev needs. The output is

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

libgfortran5 : Depends: gcc-11-base (= 11-20210417-1ubuntu1) but 11.1.0-1ubuntu1~21.04 is to be installed

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried to downgrade gcc-11-base to 11-20210417-1ubuntu1 with command `sudo apt-get install gcc-11-base=11-20210417-1ubuntu1`, but it will remove 2.6G of stuff, which I believe will crash the system. So, I didn't say yes to "You are about to do something potentially harmful."

Please let me know if you have encountered this issue before. Thanks a lot!

**Logistics**:

1. System: Ubuntu Desktop 21.04
2. Hardware: Raspberry Pi 4B (8Gb men) aarch64
3. Python: version 3.8.7 correctly installed (default)
4. I might have messed around with `/etc/apt/sources.list` since I needed to add some random repository to install python3.8 (according to some tutorials) [I highly suspect that this is causing the problem.]

Thanks a lot,

Terry

.

**To answer community suggestions**:

Thank you guys for your prompt suggestions.

1. I installed the Ubuntu 21.04 Desktop from this link https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi
2. Yes, I understand that this is a arm system, which x86 packages will fail on any raspberry pi. I simply want to install opencv on pi, the command I ran to do so is "sudo apt install libopencv-dev python3-opencv" as suggested here https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-opencv-on-ubuntu-20-04/
3. I tried that post, and it didn't solve the issue unfortunately (that's why I wrote this post). I don't have any hold packages. Aptitude did successfully install I think, but cv2 module cannot be found when I ran python
4. In my `/etc/apt/sources.list`, I have the following links. I highly think these are mal-configured. Any idea of fixing it? Thanks a lot!

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute main
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute universe
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ hirsute main universe multiverse
```

Also, when I installed python, I ran this command `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa`. Maybe this causes the issue?

Comment: Ubuntu 21?  No such release.  Ubuntu uses the *year* format for *snap* only releases, but you start with a `sudo apt install` which doesn't work on *year* format products. Please clarify your release.

Comment: If you look at https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/libgfortran5 you'll note you have/are trying to install *i386/amd64* packages it appears on what you say is an *arm64* system.  Do you understand what the *architecture* means?   Correct your sources!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: Please provide details of exactly what you did to the software sources. The staff mind-reader is on break.

Comment: Please see my edited post, for I provide more info to your suggestions there. Thanks a lot! I really hope I can get this(OpenCV) working.